# Was this answer deleted? Can I see it?

Tags: support

On October 28, 2019, I got an e-mail with a link to an answer to a question I had posted. The URL of the link is long and complex, but redirects to:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1496261/how-do-i-revert-these-permissions/1496774#1496774

Within a few days of getting that e-mail, I clicked the link, but there was no answer there. The question has since been "deleted" (actually hidden, although I am still able to access it when logged in), apparently because it got a downvote and has no answer.

The e-mail says that the answer started with: "If you're trying to restore permissions to Windows core OS files/directories, MS has a KB article...". That snippet suggests that the answer told me exactly what I wanted to know, which was documentation on how to revert a changed permission.

Was that answer deleted for some reason? Is it possible for me to see it? If I can't see the whole answer, can I at least be informed of the URL of the KB article it referenced? After all these months, I have not found the information, and I need it.

Comment: Someone commented on the answer "The referenced article is about replacing missing or corrupted system files. A system file with non-default permissions is neither. In fact, the article explains how to alter permissions in a similar way to what the Question Poster did" so I don't think it will help you anyway.

Comment: For your info the link was https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thank you for the link, so I could see for myself, and thank you for quoting the comment on the answer. Can you tell me, was the answer deleted by the person who posted it? Did he state a reason for deleting it, such as "I realized it was not the right answer to the question"?

Comment: It was deleted by the post author, shortly after the comment was posted. No reason was given.

Comment: Based on the commentary to that answer, I suspect the author of the answer deleted their answer, due to being told the answer did not answer the author’s question.  Specifically the article they were referring to was applicable to the author’s question.  However, without the author of the answer indicating that’s the case, that’s pure speculation on my part